# c++ winsock multithread http server

Tags: c++, multithreading, http, console, winsock

I am rather new to C++ and have run into a problem, when I connect to the server(using a browser) it sends a response fine and it shows up fine on the browser, however looking at the console it sent the webpage twice, a page view counter confirms this, from testing i am unsure of the order it runs.

loop listening for new connections:

```
    while (true){

    //create temp scoket for cconnetcion
    SOCKET ClientSocket;
    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    // Accept the socket from the client when it tries to connect
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

    printf("NEWCON" );
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        std::string blah;
        std::cin >> blah;
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 104;
    }

    views += 1;

    AfxBeginThread(RequestProsorses, (LPVOID)ClientSocket);

}
```

RequestProsorses function:

```
UINT  RequestProsorses(LPVOID pParam){
printf("\n NEWREC");
SOCKET ClientSocket = (SOCKET)pParam;


 #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int conResult, iSendResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
std::string returnVal = "HTTP/1.x 200 OK \n Transfer-Encoding: chunked \n\n <html><body><b>Total Page Views:</b>";

conResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
if (conResult > 0) {
    printf("Bytes received: %d\n", conResult);

    //create response to user
    returnVal +=   std::to_string(views) + "</body></html>";
    //printf(returnVal.c_str());
    // Send Responce to user

    iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, returnVal.c_str(), returnVal.length(), 0);
    if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        //printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        std::string blah;
        std::cin >> blah;
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
}
else if (conResult == 0){
    printf("Connection closing...\n");
}
else {
    printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    std::string blah;
    std::cin >> blah;
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}

// shutdown the send half of the connection since no more data will be sent
conResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
if (conResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}

closesocket(ClientSocket);

return 0;
}
```

Console output(form one view only):

> NEWCONNEWCON
>   NEWREC
>   NEWRECBytes recived: 373
>   Bytes sent: 99
>   Bytes recevied: 287
>   Bytes sent:99

Hope that's enough info for you, if not i am happy to post more of course.

if statement to check foe end of header

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= recvbuflen; i++){
    if (recvbuf[i] == '\n' && (int)recvbuf[i + 1] == -52){
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not send anything until you received the *whole* request.

Comment: Also, if you get an error in the thread, you call `WSACleanup` which of course cleans up for the whole *process*, including the main thread. That will most likely result in some undefined behavior with the other sockets still open.

Comment: And lastly, since you last in the thread does `closesocket` there's really no need to do a `shutdown`. Only do `shutdown` of the sending side if you expect to read more but not send more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply's!!, I am not sure how I can receive everything before sending, I have tried using a loop to keep running the recv function until it returns something less than 0 but when it goes to loop again it just stops at the recv function.

Comment: You need to read about [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), because it will tell you when it's done (all requests have an empty line after the header, and for plain `GET` requests there is no more). You can also make the socket non-blocking and read until you get an error telling you that `recv` would block, that means there is no more data to receive.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ..or it means that the server has just pagefaulted/whatever and the rest of the data will be along shortly.  Sync/async design has nothing to do with correct handling of protocols.

Comment: I am not sure if I am checking for the head of the header correctly  (I have added the if statement I am using to the original answer). Once "finished" has been set to true it does not run "recv" again but runs send to respond, it does send fine but it still does it twice :/

Comment: Ok, I figured out what the problem is, the second request header is asking for the favicon.ico. I feel so silly right now :/. thanks for all your help :), it was still very helpful as its given me a better understanding of how to use winsock for this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer :), thanks to @JoachimPileborg and  @MartinJames for there help!
Simply the browser was sending a second request and as the program does not check what page is being viewed(it simply sends the same page no matter what at the moment), it looked to me like it was doing the same thing twice just for one page request. the browser was trying to assess /favicon.ico just like its supposed too.

I have made changes to the code and although is by no means finished it works so here is the code if anyone's interested in the changes i made(in case there where other errors i fixed without realizing).

```
// HTMLtest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


int views = 0;

UINT  RequestProsorses(LPVOID pParam){
    printf("\n NEWREC");
    SOCKET ClientSocket = (SOCKET)pParam;
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int conResult, iSendResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
std::string returnVal = "HTTP/1.x 200 OK \n Transfer-Encoding: chunked \n\n <html><body><b>Total Page Views:</b>";
bool finished = false;
do {
    std::cout << "b";
conResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
for (int i = 0; i <= recvbuflen; i++){
    if (recvbuf[i] == '\n' && (int)recvbuf[i + 1] == -52){
        finished = true;
    }
}

if (conResult > 0) {

}
else if (conResult == 0){
    printf("Connection closing...\n");
}
else {
    printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    std::string blah;
    std::cin >> blah;
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
}



} while (conResult > 0 && finished == false);

printf("Bytes received: %d\n", conResult);
std::cout << "RECIVED: " << recvbuf;
//create response to user
returnVal += std::to_string(views) + "</body></html>";
//printf(returnVal.c_str());
// Send Responce to user

iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, returnVal.c_str(), returnVal.length(), 0);
if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    std::string blah;
    std::cin >> blah;
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
}
printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);



closesocket(ClientSocket);

return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

WSADATA wsaData;

// Initialize Winsock
int IPresult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (IPresult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", IPresult);
    return 1;
}

struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, params;
ZeroMemory(&params, sizeof(params));
params.ai_family = AF_INET;
params.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
params.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
params.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

//resolve the IP address and port to used by the server
IPresult = getaddrinfo(NULL, "80", &params, &result);
if (IPresult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", IPresult);
    std::string blah;
    std::cin >> blah;
    WSACleanup();
    return 100;
}


SOCKET ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    std::string blah;
    std::cin >> blah;
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 101;
}

// Setup the socket for HTTP
IPresult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
if (IPresult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    std::string blah;
    std::cin >> blah;
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 102;
}

//Free the memory allocated by "getadderinfo" as its no longe needed
freeaddrinfo(result);

if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    std::string blah;
    std::cin >> blah;
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 103;
}


while (true){

    //create temp scoket for cconnetcion
    SOCKET ClientSocket;
    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    // Accept the socket from the client when it tries to connect
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

    printf("NEWCON" );
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        std::string blah;
        std::cin >> blah;
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 104;
    }

    views += 1;

    AfxBeginThread(RequestProsorses, (LPVOID)ClientSocket);

}

// cleanup
//closesocket(ClientSocket);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
}
```

Sorry for how untidy it is :/

Comment: You need to get rid of your `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` response header. You are NOT sending your response data in a chunked format conforming to [RFC 2616 Section 3.6.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.6.1), so DO NOT tell the browser that you are.